# reverse engineering obfuscated .net dll

Tags: decompilation, dll, .net, c#

I am decompiling a third party `.NET dll` which was obfuscated using `codeveil`
my aim is to get full source code,

I tried decompiling using `dnSpy`, `JustDecompile` & `Reflector`
however it just shows the public methods and properties inside the dll 
and no method body is shown

something like this:

```
    public class TestManager
    {
        // Fields
        private OleDbDatabase b;

        // Methods
        public TestManager();
        public OperationResult AddRecord(XProfile record);
        public OperationResult RevokeRecord(XProfile record);
    }
```

it errors out when I try to export source code

so how do I get the source code? is it possible?
I guess at-least if I see the `IL` code then I can rewrite the functions

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Can you share the dll?

Comment: de4dot has support for codeveil.